# Configure Supervisor to manage init.d services

Tags: uwsgi, supervisord

I installed uwsgi and created a bash script, which allows me to start/stop uwsgi in the following manner: `service uwsgi [start|stop]`. This bash script is located in `/etc/init.d/uwsgi`.

Now, I want to (politely) ask Supervisor to use that script to manage the uwsgi process. All the tutorials indicate that this is not the way to do it, however I do want to be able to do both `service uwsgi stop` and `supervisorctl stop uwsgi` (not sure if I nailed the syntax of the latter) -- even though I *am* aware that the first one will not in fact stop my service because supervisor will restart it (that's exactly what I need).

Note that I'm using uwsgi in emperor mode if that matters in any way.

Comment: You need to pick one or the other. Why do you think you need to be able to use both process supervisors for uwsgi?

Comment: Because I want to have the same config across all environments, and on the local one, just not have supervisor installed. This way it will work both on production with supervisor and locally without. Also, I've seen that supervisor can do that with postfix. It doesn't use the init.d script, but somehow both ways work together.